# Can't commit from Fabric script for GitHub

Tags: python, github, fabric

I'm using Fabric to run an ANT task & then upload to GitHub. The script has worked, but not consistently so its difficult to understand why.

I've been reading on here that the process in Fabric is;

1. `git add`
2. `git commit`
3. `git push`

But I keep seeing this output;

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'git commit -m "Latest Selenium screenshots for View Employee"'

Aborting.
```

The function I've written looks like this;

```
def deploy():
    process = test()
    os.chdir('\\Documents and Settings\markw\GitTest')
    with cd('\\Documents and Settings\markw\GitTest'):
        local('git reset --soft HEAD')
        local('git pull origin master')
        local('git add -A')
        local('git commit -m "Latest Selenium screenshots for %s"' % (process))
        local('git push -u origin master')
```

What am I missing with my commit that causes a problem here? Is there another flag to combine commits that have queued up?

Comment: You path looks strange: better r'\docs' or '\\docs'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no files to commit, so git is returning a non-zero error code. This leads fabric to believe that the previous command failed, so it aborts.

To be honest, unless you're absolutely certain that git is mistaken, and there are changes to commit, then I'm tempted to believe that your script is not actually malfunctioning at all.

If you're certain there are files to commit, you should investigate why the changes aren't being picked up.

If you'd like fabric to exit in a more friendly way, you can try something like this:

```
from fabric.api import settings
import sys

def deploy():
    process = test()
    os.chdir('\\Documents and Settings\markw\GitTest')
    with cd('\\Documents and Settings\markw\GitTest'):
        with settings(warn_only=True):
            local('git reset --soft HEAD')
            local('git pull origin master')
            local('git add -A')
            commit = local('git commit -a -m "Latest Selenium screenshots for %s"' % (process))
            if commit.failed:
                print 'Nothing to commit, exiting...'
                sys.exit(0)
            else:
                local('git push -u origin master')
```

I've also added a `-a` to your git commit line, so it's also committing changes as well as added files.

Also, I'm not sure of the point of your os.chdir() line.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to understand the differences between Git & tortoise SVN so I think it should be tracking the update. The process that runs first generates images in a path `images\253\View_Employee_Use_Case\1.png` where the folder number is the revision. These files might update, so if the names don't change would the updated version be ignored? That the only issue I could think of.

Comment: `with cd()` doesn't change the directory so thats why I've got `os.chdir()`. I was going to remove the `with cd()` but not got round to it yet.

Comment: Late response, but just so you know, the `cd` context manager is for changing the directory on a remote machine. The reason it hasn't worked for you is because you're using it with `local` instead of `run` or `sudo`.